# Создать 32х битное число из массива бит - ActionScript 2.0

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

Есть бинарный массив:

```
var BinArr:Array [ 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0];
```

Мне нужно из этого массива создать 32х битное число или несколько чисел, если массив больше 32х элементов. Основная проблема в том, что `Actionscript 2.0` не поддерживает тип `uint`, и когда я использую `Number` и число больше 31 бит, то все зависает и в итоге получается -1, например, вот такой вот массив бит дает -1 после зависания:

```
var BinArr:Array [ 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ];
```

Вот, кстати, функция, которой я конвертирую массив в число:

```
function binaryToDecimal(s:String):Number{

    var n:Number = 0;

    for(var i:int=0;i<s.length;i++){
        n+=Number(s.substr(i,1))<<(s.length-1-i)
    }
    return n;
}
```

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка, ведь `Number` это `Decimal`, насколько я понял, так что должно влезать 32 бита, но почему-то не влезает, максимум что работает это 31 бит.

**UPDATE1:**
Во общем проблему решил, зависания нету, получаю сразу -1 как и должно быть по идее. Теперь проблема в обратной функции, она нормально конвертирует обратно число в бинарную строку, но не хочет конвертировать отрицательное число, вот функция:

```
function decimalToBinary(num:Number):String{
    var bin:String = "";
    while (num) {
        bin = num % 2 + bin;
        num = Math.floor(num / 2);
    }
    return (bin) ? bin : String(0);
}
```

Comment: Поясните слово "зависание". Если программа зависает, то как она выдаёт результат?

Comment: Зависает на секунд 20, потом отвисает и дает результат -1.

Comment: Лучше задайте отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Видимо, проблема в том, что [Flash AS2 интерпретирует результат сдвигов как int со знаком](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AS2LCR/Flash_10.0/help.html?content=00000631.html). На той же странице есть упоминание о том, что `&` или битовое AND, а также `^` или битовое XOR конвертирует аргументы в беззнаковый целый, а значит, и возвращает беззнаковый целый. То есть, можно попытаться обернуть сдвиг в (xor 0) и получить беззнаковое число для прибавления к имеющемуся (знаковому, но по факту вещественному) `Number`.

```
function binaryToDecimal(s:String):Number{
    var n:Number = 0;
    for(var i:int=0;i<s.length;i++){
        n+=(Number(s.substr(i,1))<<(s.length-1-i)) ^ 0);
    }
    return n;
}
```

Однако, следует учесть, что такой формат не сработает для массивов длиной выше 32, так как сдвигать на 32 целое выдаст 0 вне зависимости от значения на входе. В этом случае правильно будет использовать умножение и тип Number.

```
function binaryToDecimal2(s:String):Number {
    var two:Number=1; // power of two
    var n:Number=0; // accumulator
    for (var i:int=s.length-1;i>=0;i--) {
        if (s.charAt(i) == '1') {
            n+=two;
        } // assuming all other symbols are 0.
        two=two*2;
    }
    return n;
}
```

Вообще, по возможности стоит избегать излишнего преобразования типов, вроде сложения или сдвига символа как числа, если есть возможность интерпретировать его как символ и использовать готовое число.

UPDATE: Насчет конвертации из отрицательного числа - вот тут как раз надо использовать сдвиг и битовые операции. Трюк в том, что `Math.floor(-1/2)` равен -1, и имеем бесконечный цикл.

```
function decimalToBinary(num:Number):String{
    var bin:String = "";
    while (num!=0) {
        bin = num % 2 + bin;
        num = num >>> 1; // беззнаковый сдвиг, в итоге из -1 получится 0x7FFFFFFF
    }
    return (bin) ? bin : String(0);
}
```

Comment: Хорошо, попробую Ваш вариант, но у меня еще вопрос, я когда получал результат -1, у меня жутко все зависало при выполнении этой операции, в принципе я вот что думал, по факту мне бы подошла конвертация в HEX строку из массива бит, и обратно, может быть если конвертировать в HEX строку то зависания не будет, возможно ли конвертнуть бинарный массив сразу в HEX строку минуя приведение к `Number`?

Comment: Ну, он у вас не бинарный, а из символов, судя по тому, что функция принимает строку. Насчет конвертации в HEX - по идее, если затык есть, то заткнется там же. Лучше работать все-таки с числами как с числами, без лишней конвертации, в строку или ещё куда.

Comment: Обновил вопрос.

Answer (score -1):

Если 32 единичных бита дают -1 - значит число-приемник у вас знаковое, старший единичный бит говорит о том, что число отрицательное и вы получаете совсем не то что хотите.

Comment: Понял, А как мне записать код, что бы число приемник было беззнаковое?

Comment: Не представляю, нужно смотреть какие типы данных есть в конкретном языке.

Comment: Я вот тоже с языком абсолютно незнаком, и вроде на сколько я понял, в этой версии `as 2.0` есть только один тип `Nember` и он по факту идет `Decimal` то есть он знаковый в любом случае получается...

Comment: Тогда увы. В памяти-то, судя по всему, у вас все 32 бита как надо расположены, но интерпретация их не та.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Вопрос был почему 1<<31 получается знаковым, и как это обойти. Ответ есть в документации, но докопаться до неё действительно надо суметью Так что ответ просто ни о чем, и лучше был бы комментарием.

Comment: @Vesper Конечно же, ответ на вопрос "Не могу понять в чем ошибка" - ни о чем.

Comment: @Vesper, Вы говорите ответ есть в документации, а можно ссылку на этот ответ? И еще, тут даже проблема не том, что получается знаковое число, а в том, что при этом все зависает, почему, вот вопрос...